# How to view NuGet package implementation sources in Visual Studio Code for Mac?

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

Using `dotnet add package` brings in interface source definitions but none of the underlying implementations.

For example, my csproj file has the following section;

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="0.1.5-preview" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I am able to see interfaces for any of the types in the above packages when using "Go to Definition", however "Go to Implementations" always states that implementations are not found.

Finally, here is the Visual Studio Code installation details...

```
Version: 1.46.1
Commit: cd9ea6488829f560dc949a8b2fb789f3cdc05f5d
Date: 2020-06-17T21:17:14.222Z (1 wk ago)
Electron: 7.3.1
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 18.7.0
```

Comment: You could refer to [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/introducing-source-code-link-for-nuget-packages/) to check the `Using SourceLink`.

Comment: You can check [Debugging into the .NET Framework itself](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Debugging-into-the-.NET-Framework-itself) and will be be able to "Step-in" framework methods, but I don't know a way to enable the "Go to Implementations" option.

Comment: @AngelYordanov, Thanks.  The info. at the debugging link was very helpful.  Ultimately, I became impatient with my progress working with Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code decided to use JetBrains Rider which decompiles to C# source if/as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one way exists to view C# project package sources *using Visual Studio Code on the Mac*—i.e. by stepping into sources using the Debugger after setting the "justMyCode" flag to false in the launch.json file.

**Closer to the intent of the original question** — It is also possible to view project package sources (and framework sources, without starting up the debugger) using the JetBrains Rider IDE; by placing the cursor within any selector in the source, then typing Command+B.